# Accessing InstallShield "Support Files" from DTF (Managed Custom Action)

Tags: wix, installshield, custom-action, dtf

I have a bunch of .SQL scripts placed in the "Support Files" view of InstallShield.

I want to access those SQL scripts in my custom action (via DTF). How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

InstallShield has a custom action to extract support files, called [ISSetupFilesExtract](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/Helpnet/installshield15helplib/Ref-ISCustomActions.htm). I guess when you add a support file, this action is automatically scheduled by the InstallShield engine. Hence, you can schedule your DTF custom action after ISSetupFilesExtract and address the support files extracted to the temp directory.

Comment: It does have that custom action and I guess the files are being extracted to A directory. In InstallScript, you just need to use the SUPPORTDIR property to get the path of the "Support Files" directory (Temp?) but you can't use SUPPORTDIR from DTF. Can I just access the temp directory?

Comment: Hm, why can't you use SUPPORTDIR? I thought it can be addressed as a regular property... You're probably trying to address it from a deferred action and do not pass it via CustomActionData first?

Comment: Right. So how I pass it via CustomActionData?

Comment: For CustomAction Data, read http://www.mail-archive.com/wix-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg17875.html

Comment: I still can't access the SUPPORTDIR even from a immediate execution CA. Any other ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "can't access"? Is it empty? Do you address it like session["SUPPORTDIR"]? Is this scheduled after CostFinalize?